# how can I detect template driven form changes with [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

I'm trying to detect changes in my template-driven form but It throws an error because of NgModel is not using the standalone property.

when adding it neglects the value changes

````
        this.ngForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe((x) => {
      debugger
            if (
                x.selectedProject &&
                x.selectedProject !== this.wizardService.selectedProject
            ) {
                debugger;
                console.log(true);
            }
        })
    ```

it is not going throw the function above but when removing the standalone flag it works but I get the Ngmodel form error
````

Answer (score 1):

In a template drive form you need give "name" to your input, e.g.

```
<input name="id" [(ngModel)]="variable">
```

Has no related with `[ngModelOptions]={standalone:true}` (see that it's between `[` `]`. This attribute is used when you have **inside** a formGroup.

BTW,we can control when change in several ways

1. Split ngModel

   ```
   <input name="id" [ngModel]="variable" 
                    (ngModelChange)="variable=$event;doSomething($event)">
   ```
2. Getting with a ViewChild and subscribe to control.valueChanges

   ```
     <input name="id"
       type="text"
       [(ngModel)]="name"
       #nameInput="ngModel"
     />
     @ViewChild('nameInput',{static:true}) control!:NgModel
     ngOnInit(){
       this.control.control.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
         console.log(res)
       })
     }
   ```
3. using the event input

   ```
   <input name="id" [(ngModel)]="variable" 
      (input)="doSomething($event.target.value)">
   ```